# Updating Linked Files in Visual Studio

Tags: hyperlink, t4

I have a **Universal App** with **t4** templates: in my **Windows Project** *Models* folder and the **Windows Phone** *Models* folder links to these files.  I just update a database table with new fields and added another table, updated my **edmx** to reflect the new changes and I have a *pcl* **DataModels** *Models* folder with the original **t4** templates updated also.

Is there another way to update the links in the **Windows Phone** folder without having to **remove** it and **re-linking**?  I tried to just link the new **.g.cs class**, but it was listed outside the **.tt** file list.

Thanks!...

Answer (score 0):

First; I am no expert on EF nor universal apps but if all you need is C# files to be included one way to do so is using T4Include.

First you grab T4Include of nuget and add a TT file to your project:

```
<#
    // The relative path to project holding the source code you wish to include
    ProjectFileName = @"..\SharingCode\SharingCode.csproj"  ;
    Namespace   = "SharingCode"                             ;
#>

<#@ include file="$(SolutionDir)\packages\T4Include.1.1.4\T4\IncludeProject.ttinclude" #>
```

Hopefully it's a good enough fit for you.

Comment: Thanks FuleSnabel for the reply, I will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Today I just found out how to update my linked T4 file in VS 2013 Community by right clicking the file and selecting [Run Custom Tool].